# What's the difference between libs and implementation in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

I have already seen in some project, that in some of them is using `libs` and `libs group:` instead of `implementation` or deprecated `compile`. After local switch to `implementation` everything looks fine and works correctly.

Example:

```
libs group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
```

instead of

```
implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.6'
```

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

`libs`, `implementation`, `compile` are known as *dependency configurations* (configurations for short) in Gradle: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:what-are-dependency-configurations

They are essentially a "bucket" to place dependency in. The Java plugin defines quite a few configurations: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management

The `libs` configuration you mentioned is not part of any standard/provided Gradle plugin. So, it is provided/created by some other plugin you have applied to your project. Or you have defined the configuration yourself in your project somewhere.

The `implementation` configuration, provided by the Java plugin, are for *implementation* details of your application or library. In other words, these are "private" to your application/library and will not be available to consumers' classpath.